# É correto chamar um método, e passar seus parametros null?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, estilo-de-codificação, eventos

Por exemplo, tenho o evento de *click* de um botão chamando o método abaixo:

```
 //Evento
 this.serviçoToolStripMenuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Nivel_Serv_Click);

 //Metodo
 private void Nivel_Serv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //tipo 3 serviço
 {
    //faz alguma coisa....
 }
```

Em outro método, realizei a chamada do método acima assim:

```
 Nivel_Serv_Click(null, null);
```

É certo, fazer isso? ou seria uma gambiarra?

Comment: muito pertinente a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sim, já que não há uma sobrecarga que saiba lidar com sua chamada sem argumentos. Mas pode não ser o mais adequado.

Eu só questionaria se é o que deseja, em geral quando recebe uma notificação de que o objeto teve um evento é provável que queira saber ou fazer algo com este objeto e descartá-lo parece estranho, mas tem casos para isso.

**Eu diria que é gambiarra**, mas o mecanismo de eventos do C# é uma gambiarra. Evitar gambiarras nem sempre é pragmático, existe a gambiarra boa.

Mas esse método não é chamado por você, então ele não terá argumentos nulos. Se quer chamar um método de evento diretamente, aí talvez seja uma gambiarra maior.

Se quer ter um método que não precisa desses parâmetros, crie um método assim e chame-o, ou use um pronto (veja a [resposta do LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215860/101)). Se quer que ele seja executado dentro do método de evento, chame-o dentro do método de evento.

A forma idiomática moderna de C# é evitar o nulo tanto quanto pode. Antes eles faziam parte da filosofia da linguagem, agora só se o domínio exigir isso mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só acho que seu ... Sim, deveria já ser transparente, ou seja, "Sim, é uma gambiarra", só depois de ler o texto todo percebi isso. Pois na pergunta ta um pouco obscura para sua resposta ( É certo, fazer isso? ou seria uma gambiarra?)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza pronto, melhorei

Answer (score 12):

Se quer executar o código `{faz alguma coisa}` tanto quando a opção do menu é clicada pelo usuário ou directamente por uma chamada do seu código, o "mais correcto" será criar um método com esse código:

```
//Evento
 this.serviçoToolStripMenuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Nivel_Serv_Click);

 //Método
 private void Nivel_Serv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //tipo 3 serviço
 {
    FazAlgumaCoisa();
 }

private void FazAlgumaCoisa()
{
    //faz alguma coisa....
}
```

Quando o item do menu é clicado o sistema chama `Nivel_Serv_Click()` que por sua fez chama `FazAlgumaCoisa()`.

Quando o quiser chamar via código chame-o assim:

```
FazAlgumaCoisa();
```

Answer (score 10):

Outro ponto importante é que todos os controles que são botões têm um método chamado [`PerformClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx), ele dispara o evento de *click* do botão.

Perceba que não há erro em chamar o método do evento passando os dois argumentos como `null` **se você não** usar os parâmetros dentro de `Nivel_Serv_Click`.

Geralmente se usa o `sender`, já que ele identifica qual foi o controle que disparou o evento. Neste caso, é melhor usar o `PerformClick()`.

Comment: Bem observado..