# Como reutilizar o evento Click de um botão em outro metódo?

Tags: c#

Tenho o evento `Click` `btnReabrirCaixa_Click` e gostaria de reutilizar do processo que tem dentro desse evento em um método `ValidarAberturaCaixa()`, sem copiar e colar todo o código, como poderia ser feito isso?

Comment: joga o código do botão em um método, se não estiver utilizando o `sender` e chama o método dentro do evento, e dentro do outro método. Se quiser um exemplo, forneça um que iremos alterá-lo

Comment: ASP MVC, Web Forms? Com o que você está trabalhando?

Comment: Relacionado(duplicata ?): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215845/2541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Modularize

Separe o conteúdo de `btnReabrirCaixa_Click` em um método e chame-o em `ValidarAberturaCaixa` e `btnReabrirCaixa_Click`, como:

```
private void MetodoSeparado() {
    // ...
}

private void btnReabrirCaixa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MetodoSeparado();
}

private void ValidarAberturaCaixa() {
    // ...
    MetodoSeparado();
    // ...
}
```

## Ou dispare o evento

Você pode disparar o evento de clique, aí não precisaria separar o método. Eu só faria isso se fizesse sentido naquele momento o botão ser clicado automaticamente.

#### Windows Forms

```
private void ValidarAberturaCaixa() {
    // ...
    btnReabrirCaixa.PerformClick();
    // ...
}
```

#### WPF

```
private void ValidarAberturaCaixa() {
    // ...
    btnReabrirCaixa.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    // ...
}
```

Pra ficar reutilizável e mais organizado, pode criar um método de extensão no WPF:

```
namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
    public static class ButtonExtensions
    {
         public static void PerformClick(this Button obj)
         {
             obj.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
         }
    }
}
```

Aí pode utilizar assim:

```
private void ValidarAberturaCaixa() {
    // ...
    btnReabrirCaixa.PerformClick();
    // ...
}
```

Igual ao Windows Forms.

## Ou chame o método diretamente

Outra forma (acho feia e pode não se aplicar em todos os casos, quando houver manipulação dos parâmetros):

```
private void ValidarAberturaCaixa() {
    // ...
    btnReabrirCaixa_Click(null, null);
    // ...
}
```